# Delete observations in a panel when identifier is contained in a list of values

Tags: stata

I have an unbalanced panel with the panel id `member`

I would like to delete particular members from the data set (i.e. in every panel they appear), and would like to delete those specific members that appear in a list/vector of values.

If I have the list of values of `member` (say 1, 3, 10, 17, 173, 928) 
I would like a way to `drop` every observation where the panel `id` (member) is contained in the list.

The list is ~1500 values long, so rather than manually  typing

```
drop if member == 1
drop if member == 3
drop if member == 10

drop if member == 928
```

I would like to somehow automate this process.

Comment: A `foreach` loop is possible, but if the list of IDs to drop is "~1,500 values long" then you would probably be better off using `merge`. How is the list of IDs to drop stored?

Comment: The list itself is currently a single column in an excel file.

Can you explain in a bit more detail how I would use merge? I am very new to Stata so this might be a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

@Brendan Cox (namesake, not a relative) has the nub of the matter. To expand a bit:

Note first that

```
drop if inlist(member,1,3,10,17,173,928)
```

would be an improvement on your code, but both illegal and impractical for a very large number of values: here 1500 or so certainly qualifies as very large.

At some critical point it becomes a much better idea to put the identifiers in a file and `merge`. For more on the spirit of this, see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/selecting-subset-of-observations/

It's not a paradox that you `merge` here (temporarily making a *bigger* dataset) even though you want to make a *smaller* dataset. `merge` identifies the intersection of the datasets, which is precisely those observations you wish to `drop`. `merge` to create unions of datasets merely happens to be the main and most obvious motive for using the command, but there are others.

Comment: Read your answer after posting mine, but they should complement each other.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail how to use the merge function?

Would it simply add a column (merged values of *member* from list) that is empty when the member number in that row is not in the list, and equal to the member number when it is in the list? Then I simply drop the observations where the column with merged values is not empty?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The FAQ cited does explain. See section 3. The only difference I can see from your problem is that, as explained, you want to `drop` the intersection not `keep` it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify how the list is structured. Please remember to post all details relevant to your problem.

Below two examples.

```
clear
set more off

*----- case 1 (list in another .dta file) -----

// a hypothetical list
input ///
idcode
1
3
end

list

tempfile mylist
save "`mylist'"

// rest of data
clear
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/union.dta
list if idcode <= 4, sepby(idcode) 

merge m:1 idcode using "`mylist'", keep(master)
list if idcode <= 4, sepby(idcode) 

*----- case 2 (list in a macro) -----

clear
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/union.dta

// a hypothetical list
local mylist 1, 3

drop if inlist(idcode, `mylist')
list if idcode <= 4, sepby(idcode)
```

`help inlist` mentions the following limit:

> The number of arguments is between 2 and 255 for
>                            reals and between 2 and 10 for strings.